# Format SQL String

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, trim, charindex

I have various values in a SQL View with the following format :

SoftwareName_Language_Architecture_Type_Version_{GUID}_INSTALL.Log

Ex: `Java-v6.27_ALL_x86_MSI_pV1.0_{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416027FF}_INSTALL.Log`

I want this result in differents column :

```
SoftwareName
Architecture
Language
```

I'm stuggling with multiple `_` characters using various functions `RIGHT`,`LEFT`,`CHARINDEX`,`TRIM` and all.

Comment: In your format mask, you have 4 underscores, but in your example data, you have 6.  Do you have a rule for handling excess underscores?

Comment: I've corrected the post

Comment: In Postgres you would just use string_to_array(), but in SQL Server, you need to define a table-valued function yourself, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx

Comment: There are a lot of ready-to-wear Split functions for SQL that can be used for this.  Just google `SQL Split Function`

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to do in SQL, as there is not split function.  It is easy to do in other programming languages.    I'd consider getting the output of your SQL into a file and then processing that file with a programming language like python, for example:

```
>>> field='Java-v6.27_ALL_x86_MSI_pV1.0_{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-
>>> print '\n'.join(field.split('_'))
Java-v6.27
ALL
x86
MSI
pV1.0
{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416027FF}
INSTALL.Log
```

Or in Bash

```
echo 'Java-v6.27_ALL_x86_MSI_pV1.0_{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416027FF}_INSTALL.Log'|sed "s/_/\n/g"
Java-v6.27
ALL
x86
MSI
pV1.0
{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F86416027FF}
INSTALL.Log
```

And you can do both the SQL and the bash from the command line with something like this:

```
cat getstuff.sql | mysql -uuser -ppass -hhost db | sed "s/_/\n/g"
```